# Using React forwardRef with Typescript generic JSX arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given the following typed React component using [generic type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html), how would I go about wrapping it in React's new `forwardRef` API?

```
type Props<T> = {
  forwardedRef?: Ref<HTMLInputElement>
  ...
}

class GenericComponent<T> extends Component<Props<T>> {
  ...
}

const ComponentWithRef = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props<T>>((props, ref) => (
  <StringInput<T> {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
))
```

The above approach has no way to define the `T` generic.

Comment: I don't see any way to do it either.  Your best option may be to not use `forwardRef` and just have callers call `StringInput` directly, passing the `forwardedRef` prop.  Note that [generic components are unsound to begin with](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17949), so I wouldn't hope for full support for type checking their usage.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen - yeah, that is a worrisome edge case to using generics: specifically, that a class component instance could be backed by two different elements with different generic type annotations, when those elements share the same underlying component.  If I understand correctly, this weakness is only exposed in stateful class components, and not stateless class or functional components that don't share state across renders.  Still a valid type vulnerability exposed by how React handles the component lifecycle, though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So, to broaden the question some, this is really a question about preserving generic types in higher order functions.  The following usage of `forwardRef` will properly typecheck (in `3.0.1`)

```
const SelectWithRef = forwardRef(<Option extends string>(props: Props<Option>, ref?: Ref<HTMLSelectElement>) =>
  <Select<Option> {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />);
```

But, the `Option` generic is immediately resolved to `string`, rather than remaining as a generic.  As such, the following does not typecheck

```
const onChange: (value: 'one' | 'two') => void = (value) => console.log(value);

<SelectWithRef<'one' | 'two'>
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [ts] Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1
  value="a"
  options={['one', 'two']}
  onChange={onChange}
           ^^^^^^^^^^ [ts] Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two"'
/>
```

The relevant issue is tracked in [this Typescript issue ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a workaround:

```
type Props<T> = {
    ref?: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>;
    someProp: string; 
    testType: T;
}

const TestComponent: <T extends any>(props: Props<T>) => ReactNode = (() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
    return forwardRef(({someProp, testType}, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        console.log(someProp, testType);
        return <div ref={ref}>testasd</div>;
    });
})();
```

and then:

```
type TestType = {
    name: string;
};

const SomePage: FC = () => {
    const someRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    return (
        <div>
            <TestComponent<TestType> someProp='OK' ref={someRef} testType={{name: 'test'}}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

this compiles with no errors.

the type of `testType` is inferred correctly

the following gets an error:

```
<TestComponent<TestType> someProp='ERROR' ref={someRef} testType={'test'}/>
```

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TestType'.ts(2322)`

which is expected.