# Generics error with forwardRef: Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When using forwardRef with generics, I get `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'` or `Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-0dt6d?fontsize=14

Relevant code in CodeSandbox link above replicated here:

```
interface SimpleProps<T extends string>
  extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  random: T;
}

interface Props {
  ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function WithGenericsButton<T extends string>() {
  return React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props & SimpleProps<T>>(
    ({ children, ...otherProps }, ref) => (
      <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton" {...otherProps}>
        {children}
      </button>
    )
  );
}

() => (
  <WithGenericsButton<string> ref={ref} color="green">
    Click me! // Errors: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
  </WithGenericsButton>
)
```

A potential solution is suggested here but not sure how to implement in this context: 
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215
(Found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51898192/9973558)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So the main problem here is that you're returning the result of `React.forwardRef` in your render, which isn't a valid return type for the render func. You'd need to define the forwardRef result as it's own component, and then render that inside your WithGenericsButton higher order component, like so:

```js
import * as React from "react";

interface SimpleProps<T extends string> {
  random: T;
}

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  color: string;
}

function WithGenericsButton<T extends string>(
  props: Props & SimpleProps<T> & { ref: React.Ref<HTMLButtonElement> }
) {
  type CombinedProps = Props & SimpleProps<T>;
  const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, CombinedProps>(
    ({ children, ...otherProps }, ref) => (
      <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton" {...otherProps}>
        {children}
      </button>
    )
  );
  return <Button {...props} />;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
  return (
    <WithGenericsButton<string> ref={ref} color="green" random="foo">
      Click me!
    </WithGenericsButton>
  );
};
```

If you put that in a sandbox or playground you'll see that `props` is now typed correctly including a `random` prop of `T`

Answer (score 8):

The problem that you are getting is because of this function:

```
function WithGenericsButton<T extends string>() {
  return React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props & SimpleProps<T>>(
    ({ children, ...otherProps }, ref) => (
      <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton" {...otherProps}>
        {children}
      </button>
    )
  );
}
```

`WithGenericsButton` is not a component. It is a js function that returns a component. TS is basically telling you: hey the component `WithGenericsButton` (because you are using it as one) doesn't have a prop called `children` and it is right, it doesn't.

In your case to get a component that you can render you'll need to do something like this: `const StringButton = WithGenericsButton<string>();`

Comment: Thanks Johnny - do you mind showing me how to pass down props to `StringButton` in your case (You can modify my sandbox link)

Comment: in a simpler way, that is the issue, returning a function vs a component and not having its props defined in

Answer (score 3):

I found another good way to figure out your question. Something like this,

```
export interface Props = {
   ...yourPropsHere;
};

export interface CompoundedComponent extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> {
   yourStaticFunctionOrSomethingLikeThat: () => void;
}

const Component = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>((props, ref) => (
    <input ref={ref} {...props} />
)) as CompoundedComponent;

Component.yourStaticFunctionOrSomethingLikeThat = () => {};
```