# Infer the forwarded ref type of third party component in consumer side component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I had read this question [Generics error with forwardRef: Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750777/generics-error-with-forwardref-property-ref-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsic)

Here is my case:

```
import React from "react";

interface ThirdPartyComponentProps
  extends React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"input"> {}

const ThirdPartyComponent: React.ComponentType<ThirdPartyComponentProps> =
  React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, ThirdPartyComponentProps>(
    (props: ThirdPartyComponentProps, ref) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <input ref={ref} type="text" {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  );

interface AppProps
  extends React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof ThirdPartyComponent> {}

export const App = React.forwardRef((props: AppProps, ref) => {
  return <ThirdPartyComponent ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

Got TS type error:

```
Type '((instance: unknown) => void) | MutableRefObject<unknown> | null' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.
      Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(816, 46): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ThirdPartyComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

Since the `ThirdPartyComponent` component is a component of a third-party library, I don't know which HTML element the forward ref is used on. It may be the root element or an internal element, such as the `input` element in the example.

I know that the type of forwarding ref is `HTMLInputELement` from the error, but this is the type of ref that I learned through an error.

How to declare or infer the type of `ThirdPartyComponent` ref directly on the consumer side, that is, in the `App` component.

What's the ref type for `React.forwardRef<??, AppProps>` generic type.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBUALYKAEwAUVYAngGFckaklo8cYAM7k4cJAA861LjMTEYAOhHgI4ydJkB1YDDbJMAHnw0wAVxj4AfHADeAX0poDM+OycvPwwwqIGEjAAXJroOnpikSwCYEjWgdx8ggkRRhCybgC88rEY2pjQAO78XFbWABIsALIAMgCS1I4wAKIANkggkQA0rByZIWH6hjBS+TIuABQlCgtgxjEZwdnh07OyI0SYAJRwhW7uywpwRDAOUNRwS1fPcNZcwABuLpcvr-ZO1yQmEK7kOnjgoVShXwdBU+A82kRazm4IA9N9fgprKj3l8fnAjhRnt4FITKDQ6AwmHAAIJgMB7OQKZSqdSleI7SKMswWOqQpAQTCjIJZUI5abnbzkZSQWBwXzUfy0+mndnlKo1KwLVbrZUM4wHIEnM4eEo3O4PdJjLZizm0QHA0FA8HuRHaZGyNEuCieMlAA)

Answer (score 2):

It requires a bit of typescript gymnastic.

Since `ThirdPartyComponent` is a `React.ComponentType<ThirdPartyComponentProps>` we should start from inferinf `ComponentType`.

This is our first line:

```js
T extends React.ComponentType<infer Ref>
```

Then we need to infer the props of `ComponentType`, I mean these `ThirdPartyComponentProps` props.

```js
Ref extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
      React.InputHTMLAttributes<infer RefElement>,
      any
    >
```

`RefElement` is the element we are looking for.

Whole code:

```js
import React from "react";

interface ThirdPartyComponentProps
  extends React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"input"> { }

const ThirdPartyComponent: React.ComponentType<ThirdPartyComponentProps> =
  React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"input">>(
    (props: ThirdPartyComponentProps, ref) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <input ref={ref} type="text" {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  );

type InferHTMLElement<T> =
  (T extends React.ComponentType<infer Ref>
    ? (Ref extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<infer RefElement>, any>
      ? RefElement
      : never
    )
    : never
  )

{
  // HTMLInputElement
  type Test = InferHTMLElement<typeof ThirdPartyComponent>
}

interface AppProps
  extends React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof ThirdPartyComponent> { }

export const App = React.forwardRef<InferHTMLElement<typeof ThirdPartyComponent>>((props: AppProps, ref) => {

  return <ThirdPartyComponent ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AVAC2CgBMAFFLACeAYVyRaSenxxgAzlThwkADwa0ecxMRgA6MeAiTpsuQHVgMDskwAefHTABXGPgB8cAN5wAvlSpoRnLwnNz8gjCi4kZSMABc2uh6BhKxbEJgSLahvALCKTEmEPIeALyKiRi6mNAA7oI8NrYAEmwAsgAyAJK0zjAAogA2SCCxADSVydHGMDLF5pbWSHYOvS7ubgAUFUqbYKYJOeH507Fz8hNEmACUcKUenjtKcEQwTlC0cNuUz79wtjxgAA3NxPP7-RwuF7LUqeK4%20OCRTKlfAMNT4Ly6LH7eYIgD0oJ%204P%20eMBILBcGuFCJSj8RKp-koSNYPUwjFanSGI1i2TKFU2bGUaikmkm%20lO9HSmVsdDZUG0mEJvwA-F8bEL1KLkEldAARJAwFDAYY8Dkdc5yWzaqo9PpmgCCMBgUGAACMXEhLbLGAquaN6G4JihaEIlX9VTY-bEKQlJEDGE9rk9Y0h41AKknqJRHkS8Xi4GbbS4o-QKsz2J74KU4Kz2e0OiWYLZmRBMOwuLkIlFDDNCXSaPRGMw0Kx7WAwBaKqpNVprVMe2dTBYrE0W22jnlIgVe15fIzVJBYHBArRgnAx2A7mKalB6rwmrWoGbG82MkhW%202wpvu6kA1s9gc57jhalzLLc9xeIySivO8nzZB2xxbhK8BXLC8KYtipj4m41I%20FSQA)

You can try to replace `"input"` with `"div"` and you will see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
type RefInfer = AppProps['ref'];

export const App = React.forwardRef((props: AppProps, ref: RefInfer) => {
  return <ThirdPartyComponent ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=4&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBUALYKAEwAUVYAngGFckaklo8cYAM7k4cJAA861LjMTEYAOhHgI4ydJkB1YDDbJMAHnw0wAVxj4AfHADeAX0poDM%20OycvPwwwqIGEjAAXJroOnpikSwCYEjWgdx8ggkRRhCybgC88rEY2pjQAO78XFbWABIsALIAMgCS1I4wAKIANkggkQA0rByZIWH6hjBS%20TIuABQlCgtgxjEZwdnh07OyI0SYAJRwhW7uywpwRDAOUNRwS1fPcNZcwABuLpcvr-ZO1yQmEK7kOnjgoVShXwdBU%20A82kRazm4IA9N9fgprKj3l8fnAjhRnt4FITKDQ6AwmHAAIJgMB7OQKZSqdSleI7SKMswWOqQpAQTCjIJZUI5abnbzkfmaTAdTD0U60%20mMgDaAHJDuqALoUcjKSCwOC%20aj%20ZVgJXIOLlKo1KwLVbrc2Mg5AmJWeX0E5nDwlG53B7pMZbMWc2iA4GgoHg9yI7TI2RolwUTxkoA)