# React.forwardRef with generic Props type in flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to add `React.forwardRef` to an already existing component that looks like this:

```js
type Props<T> = {
  someProp: T,
}

const Component = <T>({someProp}: Props<T>) => {...}
```

Now this is component uses `Props<T>`, where `T` is some generic type. I'm having difficulties adding `React.forwardRef` and having no errors and no compromises on typing.

Here are some things I've tried:

```js
// Complains T doesn't exist
const Component = React.forwardRef<Props<T>, HTMLElement>((props, ref) => {...})
```

```js
// Multiple errors
type Props<T> = {
    value: T,
    onChange: T => void,
}

const ChildComponent = <T>() => React.forwardRef<Props<T>, HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
    return <div ref={ref}>123</div>;
});

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(123);
    const onChange = newValue => setValue(newValue);

    return <ChildComponent />;
};

===============================================================================================

All branches are incompatible:
 • Either inexact AbstractComponent [1] is incompatible with exact React.Element [2].
 • Or AbstractComponent [1] is incompatible with React.Portal [3].
 • Or property @@iterator is missing in AbstractComponent [1] but exists in $Iterable [4].

    ../x.jsx
       7│   onChange: T => void,
       8│ }
       9│
      10│ const ChildComponent = <T>() => **React.forwardRef<Props<T>, HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
      11│   return <div ref={ref}>123</div>;
      12│ })**;
      13│
      14│ const ParentComponent = () => {
      15│   const [value, setValue] = React.useState(123);

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_1eb3ba5b/react.js
 [2]  18│   | React$Element<any>
 [3]  19│   | React$Portal
 [4]  20│   | Iterable<?React$Node>;
        :
 [1] 297│   ): React$AbstractComponent<Config, Instance>;
```

Do you know how to use forwardRef with generic types in flow?

Answer (score 2):

Does something like this work for you?

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

function GenericComponent<T>(props: { someProp: T }) {
  return null;
}

const ForwardedRefGenericComponent = forwardRef(
  (props, ref) => <GenericComponent ref={ref} {...props} />
);


function App() {
  // Examples of using ForwardedRefGenericComponent
  return (
    <div>
      <ForwardedRefGenericComponent someProp={42} />
      <ForwardedRefGenericComponent someProp={"abc"} />
      <ForwardedRefGenericComponent someProp={true} />
      <ForwardedRefGenericComponent someProp={["x", "y"]} />
      <ForwardedRefGenericComponent someProp={{ x: "y" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL5wC+BUEIcA5FKhkwNwBQX+ArgDsMwCALgBxJAKRRgaAMINI0gTAA8AFQB8ACjD0wAZwBcuOIYZIACgdMaaASlxc4cVjD5QxAvgBtf3NQ8aKKG8ABixKRkSBRI+JLSsgpKolLwALwEUeSUOi5wegaG2Kz4ThlacGqJMnKK4GmqbvEZOGW0OAB0PfoQRrQA9FpcDtw8-EIwImIAgmBgOk44BYODcACiAB4o4L5IhnAQVHyGwAIA5nCRUCTksZS1yQ3K6QXunmL5rq5qZMAANxGPx+ahudxicQSUjqKUaKngFhA1gMbQALAAmIbAkHVcHRB7xJ71VII8yWGz9NoAIhQACM0NTsQUQWCcpDHjDnqT0uTkZSwG0YFA+Ehmbi8ezCdCkiT4bykSiqTgANrUrbU7DUgCe1IAuuLcWzbgSocS4a9moqBW08FtTDrqTRDb9Bv8gQUxlxqEA)

Flow should be smart enough to infer the types for you so there's no need to declare the types explicitly for `ForwardedRefGenericComponent`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach won't forward ref. `GenericComponent` is still a function component, which cannot be given refs

Comment: `GenericComponent` can be whatever the user wants it to be. I wrote it as a functional component for simplicity. That said, as far as I understand, a ref can be used with any component--class or functional--so this solution should not be an issue. I think it solves the issue of typing, which I believe was the main concern of the original question, and does not address how to use refs beyond that scope.

Comment: a ref can't be passed to a function component unless it was wrapped with `forwardRef` https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components, so your solution "fixes" the issue with types, but not the actual component behavior

Comment: Is my `forwardRef` in the wrong place then? I'm not entirely sure what how to use it, but I thought it would be fine the way I wrote it. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: np, this is a very common generics related issue (both Flow and Typescript affected): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884498/using-react-forwardref-with-typescript-generic-jsx-arguments https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35834

Answer (score 0):

One time generic factory can [make Flow happy](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjYqfOLMAcn0pqYG51CBPHMsAAV6OAM4AeACoA+MAF4wAbwA+qMGFEMywuDgBcYSamUBfLqipwAdqOIIMhABbko8sFOkAKAJTzZ5akIAOigCBAp8ABMXcR0xDwAaMAorHi9PHBFRJNYoXzlZRTUwVkIAV3wrME9xSIwANxKyKDlFXJMwYGlvLhMe4vVBwYtrWzAAYQY8KzIrYgV7JxjbfAwrAHMvHvUgA)

```js
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';

type Props<T> = {|
  someProp: T
|};

const withRef = <T>() => React.forwardRef<Props<T>, any>((props, ref) => {
  return (<div ref={ref} />);
});

const Component = withRef<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but there is a work-around. The [flow docs about HOCs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/#toc-exporting-wrapped-components) inspired me. Instead of trying to export a component, export a generic component factory. In the file where you want to use the component, create one or more concrete component instances with the factory.

```
// component definition file
export const createComponent = <T>(): React.AbstractComponent<Props<T>, HTMLElement> =>
  React.forwardRef<Props<T>, HTMLElement>((props, ref) => {...});
```

```
// file component is used in
import { createComponent } from './definition';
const ComponentT1 = createComponent<T1>();

const SomeComponent = (): MixedElement => {
  const ref = useRef();
  return <ComponentT1 ref={ref} />
};
```

The difference from the previous responses is that they use React function components, whereas this uses a plain JavaScript factory, that React doesn't know even existed. It's not a very elegant work-around, but I hope it helps someone out.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this example of working code will help future readers on how to use forwardRef with other props in Typescript.

```
const FancyInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>(
  (otherProps, ref) => (
    <input ref={ref} type="text" className="input bg-white py-1 px-2 w-48" {...otherProps} />
  ),
)
```